# Does Marshal.PrelinkAll improve performance?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

This [article about the .NET Compact Framework](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/netcfteam/2005/05/04/net-compact-framework-version-2-0-performance-and-working-set-faq/) suggest using `Marshal.PrelinkAll` to pay the price of generating the JIT code for platform invoke methods at application startup. A secondary benefit is to detect missing methods from external DLLs and to handle this gracefully.

In my tests, I was not able to detect much of a performance benefit (if any). Is there likely to be a performance gain from using `Marshal.PrelinkAll`?

An example usage (assuming all P/Invokes are on the current form):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PrelinkAll(this.GetType());
```

Comment: I assume most of the performance gain would be loading the dll, so perhaps you'd be able to measure a difference if you'd have P/Invokes to several custom dll's.

Comment: Most of my P/Invokes are to the standard DLLs like `coredll.dll`. I reckon there isn't much to be gained but it does no harm so is probably a reasonable idea.